# DB2 ODBC Connection with PHP in Linux

Tags: php, db2, odbc, ibm-midrange

This has become a frustrating thing for me and I'm reaching out to you guys after two days of unsuccessful attempts.
I need to make odbc connection to DB2 through php, but here's my issue:
I have installed unixODBC and php-odbc. Where can I find iSeriesAccess-6.1.0-1.2.i386.rpm
I have searched everywhere on IBM website without success.

I really appreciate it if someone could give me a link to download this rpm file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM Access (the product containing the ODBC driver) is licensed software and is only available through ESS:

> This optional package, IBM i Access Client Solutions - Linux Application Package, is only available for download on the Entitled Software Support (ESS) website under 5761-SS1 or 5770-SS1. Physical media is not available. Here is an example of downloading IBM i Access Client Solutions along with its two optional packages (Linux Application Package and Windows Application Package).

[Obtaining Access Client Solutions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1010355)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
Is there a way to connect to DB2 without this rpm package.

Comment: An alternative way to connect to a System i database might be to use the IBM JDBC driver and the ODBC-JDBC bridge, but the setup will obviously be more complex, and you will still need to obtain the appropriate license JAR (`db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar`), which, again, is not free.

Comment: @DanielSh The only other option for PHP that I am aware of is using the [IBM DB2](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ibm-db2.php) interface and purchasing a DB2 Connect license.

Comment: The [JTOpen Project](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/) maintains the open source JDBC drivers which IBM distributes for connecting to OS/400, i5/OS, and IBM i systems.  The DB2JCC driver is designed for DB2 LUW & z/OS, but is not designed for DB2 for i, and does not support its full feature-set.

Answer (score 1):

IBM i Access is not free software. There's an IBM [Technote explaining](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1010355) how to obtain the software. In short, you need to log in to the IBM ESS (Entitled Software Support) site  at the following URL: http://www-304.ibm.com/servers/eserver/ess/index.wss

Answer (score 0):

My company uses IBM i Access, however, the files had to be downloaded via the company that set up our server. They had access in ESS to download the drivers, whereas the account that we had in-house didn't. I guess that means the license is theirs and not ours.